# Updating nested document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to update a hash that's nested in a MongDB document.
I know about the `$push` function for arrays, and `$set` for completely overwriting elements, but I can't quite get the behaviour I'm looking for.

Here's what I'm trying to get:

**Before:**

```
{
  'id' => 1234,
  'evaluators' => {
    'A' => { 'x' => 2, 'y' => 4 },
  }
}
```

**Expected, after:**

```
{
  'id' => 1234,
  'evaluators' => {
    'A' => { 'x' => 2, 'y' => 4 },
    'B' => { 'x' => 3, 'y' => 5 },
  }
}
```

I've tried doing (in Ruby):

```
coll.update({ :id => id },
            { '$set' => {
                'evaluators' => {
                    evaluator_name => { 'adequacy' => adequacy, 
                                        'fluency'  => fluency }
                }
            } } )
```

But it overwrites the contents of my `evaluators` hash and I end up with:

```
{
  'id' => 1234,
  'evaluators' => {
    'B' => { 'x' => 3, 'y' => 5 },
  }
}
```

I could do a query to load the entire document into Ruby, change the data and re-insert it to the DB but I was wondering if there was a better way that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
coll.update({ :id = > id }, { '$set' => {
    "evaluators.#{evaluator_name}" => {
        'adequacy' => adequacy, 'fluency' => fluency
    }
}})
```