# Update nested hash MongoDB - Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

I'm trying to update a hash in a MongoDB doc with a simple value but it store the value in an array. I use the ruby driver for mongo

Code will explain better because my english is bad.

**What I have :**

```
{
    'id' : ...
    'stream' : {
            "1406481985(a timestamp)" : 35603
     }
}
```

**What I want :**

```
{
    'id' : ...
    'stream' : {
            "1406481985" : 35603,
            "1406481990" : 15000
     }
}
```

**What I get :**

```
{
    'id' : ...
    'stream' : {
            "1406481985" : 35603,
            "1406481990" : [
                                   15000
            ]
     }
}
```

**How did I get there :**

```
views = 15000
time = Time.now
coll.find_and_modify({
    query: {:id => id},                                      
    update: {'$push' => {"stream.#{time}" => views}},                           
})
```

I've already tried with [Updating nested document in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292707/updating-nested-document-in-mongodb) and I can't see what I do wrong

Comment: You use [push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) which appends elements to an Array. I suppose it creates the Array for a first element, so you end up with `[ value ]`. However, you can probably use [set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to insert a single value. So something like `'$set' => { "stream.#{time}" => views }`. I don't have MongoDB myself, so you should first try it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniël Knippers is correct — using `$set` should work. I also notice you are using `id` instead of '_id`. Perhaps a typo?

---

edit: note that it's usually not recommended to have dynamic key values as they are difficult to index and query. Consider a `stream` structure of hashes inside an array:

```
{
    '_id' : ...
    'stream' : [
            {'time' : 1406481985, 'views': 35603},
            {'time' : 1406481990, 'views': 15000}
    ]
}
```

Now you can easily query the `time` and `views` fields.